# Mongoose keep getting MongoServerError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with 5 items in it. They look like this:

```
[
    {
        "brands": ["philips"],
        "departments": [],
        "markets": ["TR"],
        "deleted": false,
        "public": true,
        "name": "test",
        "account_id": 2,
        "creator_user_id": 7,
        "creator_user_name": "Murat"
    }
]
```

To search through this collection I'm using the following query:

```
db.collection.find(
{
    "$and": [
        {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "brands": {
                        "$in": ["philips"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "brands": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "departments": {
                        "$in": ["foo","bar"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "departments": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "deleted": false
        },
        {
            "account_id": 2
        }
    ]
}
)
```

But I'm constantly having this error:

```
MongoServerError: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField.
```

I am 100% sure that there is no mistake or typo in the query. It looks like a version error, but I tried many mongoose version updates, the error persists.

I'm using [mongoose 6.2.9](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)

Comment: It's working here. https://mongoplayground.net/p/rY9DJi9UFgU .

Comment: @Erenn Yes, I tried there too. It works there but not on my computer. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Are there any other queries running at the same time? because this query looks fine to me

Comment: @AnveegSinha No there aren't. Could mongoose models be causing this?